# How to cure "the screen saver syndrome"?

Tags: screen, background-process

When I close the flip cover or the screen saver goes on (screen goes black) some applications often either stop working, work irregularly or not at all. These include

1. ES File Explorer (ftp/cloud)
2. Canon Camera Window
3. Video recording (I think it was stock app Camera)

Of course I could experiment with turning off the screen saver and leaving the cover open. But I would prefer a more thorough solution. Once I wasn't able to rig up the phone for a video shoot, due to this problem.

For some reason it is also very irregular. When connection is good ES File Explorer has no problem with or without screen saver on. But with a slightly slower connection, FTP and cloud copy breaks after every 3-4 files about. But with cover open also slower connection works ok. I've already checked the "[WiFi policy](http://www.jethrocarr.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/wifi_sleep_fix.png)", and it's set to "Always on" – so that's not the factor here.

Galaxy Note 3, Android 5.0

Comment: So what goal do you want to reach? Keeping the screen alive when a certain app is running in foreground?

Comment: The apps should work w. cover closed or screen saver on.

Comment: That leaves contacting the developers to implement the tasks as background activities. Not much you can do about how apps act when the screen is "shut off". But if you check e.g. our [automation](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) and [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) tag-wikis you'll find there are apps keeping your screen on when a defined app runs in foreground (I e.g. use *Tasker* for that when my eBook or RSS reader is running in foreground). That way you at least have not to take manual actions each time.

Comment: Indeed :) Also see: [How do I keep my camera active on Android even when the phone is locked and screen sleeps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/94118/16575) / [Turn screen off without Android sleeping](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/119770/16575) / [How to turn off screen without affecting anything else?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/23130/16575) / [Is there a way to force an app to remain running in the background no matter what?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25470/16575)

Comment: Thanks for the links. / For some reason it is also very irregular. When connection is good ES File Explorer has no problem with or without screen saver on. But with a slightly slower connection, FTP and cloud copy breaks after every 3-4 files about. But with cover open also slower connection works ok. / Maybe also other factors involved.

Comment: With FTP/Cloud there is another problem superimposed: Sometimes the Android client just breaks after each 3-4 files even w screen on. But Filezilla in a computer will continue transfer. When you read Filezilla logs it reset the connection all the time. Android client (like ES File Explorer) do not have this capacity yet, as far as I know.

Comment: Another finding: [How can I keep an app (not made by me) running in the background continuously](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/111448/16575) (I've just added the `background` tag to your question while integrating facts from the comments above).